# Iterating simultaneously over ref / cref ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a function that takes two integer vectors. First vector is passed as a reference, the second as reference to a const. I want to iterate through both vectors simultaneously, and update the first vector. So something like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>

void foo(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int> const& b) 
{
        boost::tuple<int&, int const&> x;
        BOOST_FOREACH(x, boost::combine(a,b)) {
           int& v1 = x.get<0>();
           int const& v2 = x.get<1>();
           v1 = v1 + v2 + 5;
        }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   
  std::vector<int> a(3,10);
  std::vector<int> b(3,10);

  foo(a,b);
  for (int v : a) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is iterating over two ranges where one is ref and the other is ref const. How do that correctly using boost:combine/for loop? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you tag your question c++11 and use the boost tuple and foreach?

Comment: And why do you pass the second one as a const reference?

Comment: And third, can you put a code that we can actually compile and run? Or in the worst case, that we can edit so that it can compile?

Comment: 1. Removed c++11;  2. No particular reason, since b is not modified, it is passed as const (trying to learn if what I'm asking is possible), 3. Hopefully you can compile the example that shows the issue.

Comment: @Chiel The C++11 tag is OK since the code uses range-for etc. Sure, most of boost use is unnecessary, but you should be more clear that it's what you mean. No point in obfuscating things.

Comment: @Chiel because C++11 does not support tuple-unpacking within ranged-for like that? Have you tried?

Comment: @KubaOber ^ I'd be interested to see you write this without a range-zip thing from a library. I'm pretty sure it won't be nearly as readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't fully leverage C++11's type deduction. Also, when iterating over integers, it's pointless to access them by reference.

The reason your code didn't compile was two-fold: 1. You can't default-construct a tuple with references, and 2. You can't change its value when it has a const-reference. The `boost::tuple<int&, int const&> x;` was unnecessary anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>

void foo(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int> const& b)
{
   for(auto x : boost::combine(a,b))
      x.get<0>() += x.get<1>() + 5;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a(3,10);
   std::vector<int> b(3,10);
   foo(a,b);
   for (auto v : a)
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Of course you really should use `std::transform`, but this shows that your code would work if only you leveraged C++11 a bit more :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. It make sense now. I agree I wouldn't use it with int. Actual code is using more complicated structs but I just reduced the problem statement to use vector of ints for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

At least if I'm reading the Boost stuff correctly, you seem want something similar to:

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), 
               b.begin(),
               a.begin(),
               [] (int x, int y) { return x + y + 5; });
```

As it stands now, this uses C++11. If you need it without C++11, you can undoubtedly use Boost Lambda to accomplish about the same thing, or you can write a function object yourself:

```
struct combine { 
    int operator()(int x, int y) { return x + y + 5; }
};

void foo(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int> const & b)
{       
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), 
                   b.begin(),
                   a.begin(),
                    combine());
}
```

Also note that `std::vector<int>& const b` is incorrect. You almost certainly intended to have: `std::vector<int> const &b` instead. With the `const` *after* the `&`, it's saying that the reference itself is `const`. Moving it before means that what the reference refers to is `const`. The former makes no sense (you can't apply `const` to a reference; to the extent that the concept of const reference makes any sense at all, every reference is always const).